# Do not smooth adjacent faces together

Tags: modeling

I would like to smooth green faces together and red faces together on my model (see left part of the screenshot).
[image]
So, in edit mode, I select the green faces and I apply smooth: "Menu > Face > Shade Smooth". Then, I do the same for the red faces.
Problem: the red and green faces are also smooth together. Proof: there is only one edge normal between the green and the red faces.
How can I avoid the smooth between the green and the red faces ?

Comment: bevel the edges

Answer (score 0):

Go to your settings of that object and check this:

[image]

Then go to your object, select edges you want to be sharp and not smooth and use RMB and select this:
[image]

Blue lines are your sharp lines